# Segmentation Fault in linux

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I compiled the code and ran it, it says `Segmentation Fault`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char weather_value;
    char weather_incoming[2000];

    FILE *in;
    in=fopen("home/pi/weather_project/weather_incoming.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i<2000;i++)
    {
        fscanf(in,"%c",&weather_incoming[i]);
    }

    char* tagStartBegin = strstr(weather_incoming,"<pty");
    char* tagStartEnd = strstr(tagStartBegin,">");
    char* value = tagStartEnd+1;
    char* tagEndBegin = strstr(tagStartEnd,"</pty>");
    *tagEndBegin = '\0';
    weather_value=*value;
    printf("%c",weather_value);
    fclose(in);
}
```

I have to find weather value from the txt file, between `<pty>` and `</pty>` A guy helped me about this. When I compiled it on windows(codeblocks), it worked perfectly, but when I compiled it on linux(gcc), it keeps sending me `Segmentation Fault`.
How can I work out of it?
I don't know any information about what part is wrong because the error message was only `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: You should use a debugger (on Linux, there is gdb).

Comment: There are many issues with code. File handle `in` will be wrong and you are trying to read from it. Are you sure `home` instead `/home` ??

Comment: Looks really strange to read the file char by char `fscanf()`. I can bet your bug is connected to that. Use `fread()` instead, and read the whole file in one read statement. I guess that will do the trick.

Comment: that was the problem thx  :)

Comment: Always check return values of functions such as `fopen`.

Comment: Alternatives would be `fgets()` to read a line at a time, or `fgetc()` to read one character at a time. The `*scanf()` function familiy should only be used for *well-formatted* data (and perhaps not even then).

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with the code presented:

1. You don't check if `fopen` succeeded. What if the file you are trying to open doesn't exist?
2. You loop to read blindly does 2000 `fscanf` calls to read a character. What if the file contains less than 2000 characters?
3. You pass a non NUL-terminated string to `strstr`, invoking Undefined Behavior.
4. You don't check if `strstr` succeeded.
5. If you use C89, then you need a `return` statement for `main`.

Solutions:

1. Check `fopen`'s return value. If it is `NULL`, opening failed. You should take neccessary action if this was the case.
2. Instead of blindly iterating 2000 times, read until `fscanf` fails (This happens when `fscanf` returns `EOF`) or when the maximum buffer size has reached. Note that there are better ways to read rather than reading character by character.
3. You should NUL-terminate your array after the loop. Note that you need to reserve one extra space for that.
4. Check `strstr`'s return value. If it is `NULL`, it indicates that `strstr` failed to find the needle in the haystack. You should take neccessary action if this was the case.
5. Add `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` at the end of `main`. And one of the standard forms of `main` is `int main(void)`, not `int main()`.

Comment: I would also add a bullet point about the missing return value  in `main()` ...